# Writing a double join to get the subcategory of the product

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

Making a double join to sort out the subcategory

I am writing a join to grab the subcategory from another table. But the problem that I have is that the subcategory does not have a unique id. The subcatogory is made from the `xncatcode` and the `catid` together. They are both in the `sub_cat`table. When you look in the `producten` table you see `xngroupcode` (cat) and `xncatdesc` (subcat).

The problem I am now facing is that I get the right `productgroup` back. But the wrong `sub_cat`. seen I join them both separately (I think)

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    * 
FROM 
    froets.producten
    left JOIN  froets.productcategorieën as PGROUP 
        on froets.PGROUP.productcategorienummer = froets.producten.xngroupcode 
    left JOIN  froets.sub_cat as PCAT
    on froets.producten.xncatncode = froets.PCAT.subcatid 
    left JOIN  froets.sub_cat as SCAT 
        on froets.SCAT.catid = froets.PGROUP.productcategorienummer 
WHERE 
    froets.producten.itemdesc LIKE '%flessen%'
    or froets.producten.brand like '%flessen%'
```

`Extra data` :)

In the `producten` table are all products included the `xncatcode` and the `xngroupcode` (these are both in the `sub_cat`). So is there any possibility to join them `there`.

```
# id, model, itemcode, itemdesc, extdesc, itemkeywords, size, sizegrid, gender, weightgr, lengthcm, heightcm, widthcm, diametercm, sizecombined, qtypercarton, decopackagingindiv, decopackagingindivtype, decopackaging, grossweightkg, nettweightkg, exportlcm, exportwcm, exporthcm, countryoforigin, hscode, impallmethods, impmethoddefault, impallpositions, imppositiondefault, imppositionsimpledefault, impwidthdefaultmm, impheightdefaultmm, impdiameterdefaultmm, impsizedefaultmm, maxcoloursdefault, brand, xngroupcode, xngroupdesc, xncatncode, xncatdesc, colordesc, simplecolor, pmscolorreference, basiccolor, peninkcolor, material, batterytype, features, bestseller, eancode, thematicitem, compliances, imagemain, imagedecoy1, imagedecoy2, imagedecoy3, imagepackage, imagefront, imageback, imageextra1, imageextra2, imageextra3, imagedetail1, imagedetail2, imagedetail3, imageprintlinesdefault, marksegment, maincat, eoycat, launchdate, language, hexcolor, imagegroup, imagemood1, imagemood2, imagemood3, imagemodel, videourl1, videourl2, newitem, id, productcategorienaam, productcategorienummer, productcategoriegroep, GroepAfbeelding, id, naam, subcatid, catid, id, naam, subcatid, catid
'44870', '104231', '10423100', 'zaklamp flessenopener', 'Omega zaklamp. Aluminium. ', 'Lamp, lampen, zaklamp, zaklampen, lantaarn, lantaarns, zaklantaarn, zaklantaarns, veiligheidslamp, veiligheidslampen,', '', '', 'None', '48', '', '10', '', '2,5', '10 x Ø 2,5 cm', '200', 'No', '', '10 / Joined bubble bag', '12', '11,4', '32', '34', '24', 'China (volksrepubliek)', '8513100000000000000000', 'Tampondruk, Lasergraveren', 'Tampondruk', 'romp', 'Lamp left, button top,On colored part', 'romp', '35', '10', '', '35 x 10 mm', '4', 'Bullet', '12', 'Tools & Torches', '1', 'Zaklampen', 'Gun metal', 'Midden grijs', '', 'Grijs', '', 'Aluminium.', '', '', '', '8713159202448', 'GUNMETAL', 'Batterijrichtlijn, WEEE, RoHS , Getest op cadmium ', '10423100.jpg', '10423100_PP_Y1.jpg', '', '', '', '10423100_F1.jpg', '', '', '10423100_E2.jpg', '', '', '', '', '10423100_1_1297_1927.jpg', 'Bullet', 'N', 'N', 'JAN16', 'NL', '6F6E71', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'false', '20', 'Tools & Torches', '12', NULL, '', '1', 'Sweat Shirts', '1', '21', '20', 'Auto accessoires', '3', '12'
'44870', '104231', '10423100', 'zaklamp flessenopener', 'Omega zaklamp Aluminium. ', 'Lamp, lampen, zaklamp, zaklampen, lantaarn, lantaarns, zaklantaarn, zaklantaarns, veiligheidslamp, veiligheidslampen,', '', '', 'None', '48', '', '10', '', '2,5', '10 x Ø 2,5 cm', '200', 'No', '', '10 / Joined bubble bag', '12', '11,4', '32', '34', '24', 'China (volksrepubliek)', '8513100000000000000000', 'Tampondruk, Lasergraveren', 'Tampondruk', 'romp', 'Lamp left, button top,On colored part', 'romp', '35', '10', '', '35 x 10 mm', '4', 'Bullet', '12', 'Tools & Torches', '1', 'Zaklampen', 'Gun metal', 'Midden grijs', '', 'Grijs', '', 'Aluminium.', '', '', '', '8713159202448', 'GUNMETAL', 'Batterijrichtlijn, WEEE, RoHS , Getest op cadmium ', '10423100.jpg', '10423100_PP_Y1.jpg', '', '', '', '10423100_F1.jpg', '', '', '10423100_E2.jpg', '', '', '', '', '10423100_1_1297_1927.jpg', 'Bullet', 'N', 'N', 'JAN16', 'NL', '6F6E71', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'false', '20', 'Tools & Torches', '12', NULL, '', '1', 'Sweat Shirts', '1', '21', '33', 'Gereedschapssetjes', '2', '12'
'44870', '104231', '10423100', 'zaklamp flessenopener', 'Omega zaklamp  Aluminium. ', 'Lamp, lampen, zaklamp, zaklampen, lantaarn, lantaarns, zaklantaarn, zaklantaarns, veiligheidslamp, veiligheidslampen,', '', '', 'None', '48', '', '10', '', '2,5', '10 x Ø 2,5 cm', '200', 'No', '', '10 / Joined bubble bag', '12', '11,4', '32', '34', '24', 'China (volksrepubliek)', '8513100000000000000000', 'Tampondruk, Lasergraveren', 'Tampondruk', 'romp', 'Lamp left, button top,On colored part', 'romp', '35', '10', '', '35 x 10 mm', '4', 'Bullet', '12', 'Tools & Torches', '1', 'Zaklampen', 'Gun metal', 'Midden grijs', '', 'Grijs', '', 'Aluminium.', '', '', '', '8713159202448', 'GUNMETAL', 'Batterijrichtlijn, WEEE, RoHS , Getest op cadmium ', '10423100.jpg', '10423100_PP_Y1.jpg', '', '', '', '10423100_F1.jpg', '', '', '10423100_E2.jpg', '', '', '', '', '10423100_1_1297_1927.jpg', 'Bullet', 'N', 'N', 'JAN16', 'NL', '6F6E71', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'false', '20', 'Tools & Torches', '12', NULL, '', '1', 'Sweat Shirts', '1', '21', '47', 'Zakmes', '4', '12'
'44870', '104231', '10423100', 'zaklamp flessenopener', 'Omega zaklamp Aluminium. ', 'Lamp, lampen, zaklamp, zaklampen, lantaarn, lantaarns, zaklantaarn, zaklantaarns, veiligheidslamp, veiligheidslampen,', '', '', 'None', '48', '', '10', '', '2,5', '10 x Ø 2,5 cm', '200', 'No', '', '10 / Joined bubble bag', '12', '11,4', '32', '34', '24', 'China (volksrepubliek)', '8513100000000000000000', 'Tampondruk, Lasergraveren', 'Tampondruk', 'romp', 'Lamp left, button top,On colored part', 'romp', '35', '10', '', '35 x 10 mm', '4', 'Bullet', '12', 'Tools & Torches', '1', 'Zaklampen', 'Gun metal', 'Midden grijs', '', 'Grijs', '', 'Aluminium.', '', '', '', '8713159202448', 'GUNMETAL', 'Batterijrichtlijn, WEEE, RoHS , Getest op cadmium ', '10423100.jpg', '10423100_PP_Y1.jpg', '', '', '', '10423100_F1.jpg', '', '', '10423100_E2.jpg', '', '', '', '', '10423100_1_1297_1927.jpg', 'Bullet', 'N', 'N', 'JAN16', 'NL', '6F6E71', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'false', '20', 'Tools & Torches', '12', NULL, '', '1', 'Sweat Shirts', '1', '21', '48', 'Zaklampen', '1', '12'
'44870', '104231', '10423100', 'zaklamp flessenopener', 'Omega zaklamp Aluminium. ', 'Lamp, lampen, zaklamp, zaklampen, lantaarn, lantaarns, zaklantaarn, zaklantaarns, veiligheidslamp, veiligheidslampen,', '', '', 'None', '48', '', '10', '', '2,5', '10 x Ø 2,5 cm', '200', 'No', '', '10 / Joined bubble bag', '12', '11,4', '32', '34', '24', 'China (volksrepubliek)', '8513100000000000000000', 'Tampondruk, Lasergraveren', 'Tampondruk', 'romp', 'Lamp left, button top,On colored part', 'romp', '35', '10', '', '35 x 10 mm', '4', 'Bullet', '12', 'Tools & Torches', '1', 'Zaklampen', 'Gun metal', 'Midden grijs', '', 'Grijs', '', 'Aluminium.', '', '', '', '8713159202448', 'GUNMETAL', 'Batterijrichtlijn, WEEE, RoHS , Getest op cadmium ', '10423100.jpg', '10423100_PP_Y1.jpg', '', '', '', '10423100_F1.jpg', '', '', '10423100_E2.jpg', '', '', '', '', '10423100_1_1297_1927.jpg', 'Bullet', 'N', 'N', 'JAN16', 'NL', '6F6E71', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'false', '20', 'Tools & Torches', '12', NULL, '', '1', 'Sweat Shirts', '1', '21', '49', 'Meetlinten', '8', '12'
'44870', '104231', '10423100', 'zaklamp flessenopener', 'Omega zaklamp  Aluminium. ', 'Lamp, lampen, zaklamp, zaklampen, lantaarn, lantaarns, zaklantaarn, zaklantaarns, veiligheidslamp, veiligheidslampen,', '', '', 'None', '48', '', '10', '', '2,5', '10 x Ø 2,5 cm', '200', 'No', '', '10 / Joined bubble bag', '12', '11,4', '32', '34', '24', 'China (volksrepubliek)', '8513100000000000000000', 'Tampondruk, Lasergraveren', 'Tampondruk', 'romp', 'Lamp left, button top,On colored part', 'romp', '35', '10', '', '35 x 10 mm', '4', 'Bullet', '12', 'Tools & Torches', '1', 'Zaklampen', 'Gun metal', 'Midden grijs', '', 'Grijs', '', 'Aluminium.', '', '', '', '8713159202448', 'GUNMETAL', 'Batterijrichtlijn, WEEE, RoHS , Getest op cadmium ', '10423100.jpg', '10423100_PP_Y1.jpg', '', '', '', '10423100_F1.jpg', '', '', '10423100_E2.jpg', '', '', '', '', '10423100_1_1297_1927.jpg', 'Bullet', 'N', 'N', 'JAN16', 'NL', '6F6E71', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'false', '20', 'Tools & Torches', '12', NULL, '', '3', 'Outdoor Fleece', '1', '23', '20', 'Auto accessoires', '3', '12'
```

How can I get the right subcategory back :)?

Comment: _"But the problem that I have is that the subcategory does not have a unique id"_ - Isn't the column `id` a unique id? IMHO, your database design looks very strange. How are all these tables actually connected? Please show us some example data.

Comment: No, that is the problem. All data in these tables is read from an xml file, where the only resemblance is the combination of two values `subcatid` and `catid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you seem to be missing a JOIN condition on the sub categories.

This :

```
LEFT JOIN  froets.sub_cat as PCAT 
    ON froets.producten.xncatncode = froets.PCAT.subcatid
```

Should be written as :

```
LEFT JOIN  froets.sub_cat as PCAT 
    ON froets.producten.xncatncode = froets.PCAT.subcatid 
    AND froets.producten.xngroupcode = froets.PCAT.catid
```